# Why does margin: auto only work horizontally and not vertically?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have seen that while developing websites, vertically centering a container (of fixed height) inside a container of random height always comes as a nightmare for the web developer (at least, me) while when it comes to horizontal centering a container (of fixed width) inside a container of random width, the `margin:0px auto;` tends to serve an easy way out in the standard model.

When things can be as simple as that why doesn't CSS work out with the `margin:auto 0px;` when it comes to centering a container of fixed height inside a container of random height? Is there any specific reason to do so?

Comment: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html offers some insight: "HTML layout traditionally was not designed to specify vertical behavior. By its very nature, it scales width-wise, and the content flows to an appropriate height based on the available width. Traditionally, horizontal sizing and layout is easy; vertical sizing and layout was derived from that."

Comment: true. but still, i have a gut feeling it could be much improved. it just feels awkward you can't use vertical-align:middle, unless the container is displayed as table-cell.

Comment: @jblasco: I had already read the page you had referred to, but seems I didn't find the answer satisfactory. Reason: HTML was traditionally only intended to show/share simple textual data when it was devised at CERN, but then there have been so many changes when you compare the traditional HTML to HTML5. Then isn't it high time to adapt what promotes the ease of access?

Comment: @ptriek: Well... `vertical-align` is meant for text, not boxes. Perhaps it could have been called `vertical-text-align` or something, but that's how it was first defined, so...

Comment: Anyway I suspect this has something to do with how vertical margins collapse.

Comment: @ikartik90 It's true the vertical standards could use an update to deal with the modern way web sites are built, where we want to control both horizontal and vertical content. But I also think that so many sites are currently built on the assumption that `margin: auto` does nothing vertically, that it may be "too late" to change it, without a lot of backlash.

Comment: @ptriek and @BoltClock - I would argue that `vertical-align` is perfect in this scenario. See my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's really less of a nightmare than you think, just don't use margins. `vertical-align` is really what you should rely on for fluid-height vertical centering. I threw together a quick demo to demonstrate my point:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

#any-height {
  background: #000;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
<div id="any-height"></div>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/jLXMS/

Comment: I've used vertical-align, but doesn't serve a satisfactory solution at most places. Reason: The problem with `vertical-align` is that it is not well compatible with all browsers. For reference [check this link](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vertical-align#compatibilitysection).
So no points fella. :(

Comment: [There are tools out there that can verify if something works on other browsers](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html), so you don't have to rely on charts that arbitrarily label things as buggy... I'm pretty sure that this works in all major browsers, and if you're looking for extended compatibility, you should check [this article](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/).

Comment: One question- why're you using the empty span in your code? didn't get the reason. And though you might have a point where you stand, my question is not what should I use when I need to vertically center a container but why does `margin:auto 0px` not work to vertically center a container. Thanks for the Adobe tool though. Works great.

Comment: Well, I figured I'd offer you an alternative. You use an empty `<span>` because `vertical-align` aligns elements relative to their siblings. If an element has no siblings, it will not be vertically aligned.

Comment: Thanks @Wex. I waited all this time to accept this answer in anticipation that someone someday would respond with some better solution to the question as even though your way seems to work but its a mere fix and not a recommended way any webpage should be coded. Thanks anyway for your technique has at least served us with one way of fixing the auto vertical-alignment issue.

Answer (score 10):

The right answer for your question is that `margin: auto 0` doesn't work the same way that `margin: 0 auto` works because `width: auto` doesn't work the same way `height: auto` does.

Vertical auto margin works for absolutely positioned elements with a known height.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use flexbox parent

One of advantages of using `margin: auto` compared to `justify-content: center` / `align-items: center` is ability to [scroll child item that is overflowing parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**CSS**

```
.aligncenter{
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: box;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -moz-box-align: center;
      flex-align: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -moz-box-pack: center;
      flex-pack: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="aligncenter">
    ---your content appear at the middle of the parent div---
</div>
```

```css
.aligncenter {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  flex-align: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  flex-pack: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="aligncenter">
  ---your content appear at the middle of the parent div---
</div>
```

**Note**

This CSS class work with almost all browsers

Comment: this does not work - probably because there is no such display property called "box". downvoted