# transform an old layout to flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Currently I have this layout.

```css
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    #wrapper {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      background-color: red;
    }
    header {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
      background-color: green;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #header-top {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      outline: 1px dotted red;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    #header-middle {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      background-color: yellow;
      outline: 1px dotted red;
    }
    #header-bottom {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: grey;
      outline: 1px dotted red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div id="header-top">
      <p>I am fixed at the top</p>
    </div>
    <div id="header-middle">
      <p>I am vertically centered</p>
    </div>
    <div id="header-bottom">
      <p>I am stuck at the bottom but not fixed</p>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

How do I use flexbox here to get the same layout.

- The html, body and #wrapper needs to expand visually to surround all the child elements.
- The header is to fill the entire viewport.
- The #header-top is fixed at the top containing a logo floated to left and navigation floated to right with no explicit height.
- The #header-middle is to be vertically centered inside the header.
- The #header-bottom is like a sticky footer stuck at the bottom but no fixed.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ao0mjyu/15/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```css
header {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
  flex-direction: column; /* Stack vertically */
  height: 100%; /* As tall as the containing block */
  justify-content: space-between; /* Distribute the flex items */
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html, body, header {
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
header > div {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
#header-top {
  background-color: blue;
}
#header-middle {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#header-bottom {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="header-top">
    <p>I am fixed at the top</p>
  </div>
  <div id="header-middle">
    <p>I am vertically centered</p>
  </div>
  <div id="header-bottom">
    <p>I am stuck at the bottom but not fixed</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: The html, body and #wrapper needs a min-height: 100%, the header needs a min-height: 100vh, the #header-top needs a position: fixed, top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, width: 100%. And if I remove the #header-top, the #header-content does not center vertically and moves top. Can't get it to work with align-self: center and align-self: flex-end.

Comment: @JawadAsgharAli Not sure why you need those, but add them if you want. If you want to center `#header-middle` even if `#header-top` is removed, use `#header-middle{margin: auto 0}`.

Comment: hmm. not sure what you getting at. no such thing as margin: auto 0 for vertical center. It's margin: 0 auto for horizontal center. The #header-middle needs to be vertically center even if there is no #header-top.

Comment: @JawadAsgharAli Yes, `margin: 0 auto` centers horizontally and `margin: auto 0` centers vertically. So use the second one.

Comment: margin: auto 0; does NOT center vertically!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415661/using-marginauto-to-vertically-align-div

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620200/why-does-auto-attribute-for-margin-not-work-vertically-while-it-works-horizontal

Comment: `margin: auto 0` centers vertically in flexbox.